How to expose action items from child to parent?
I have a parent component that renders several different types of child components base on data model types.
Also, design requires that parent should hold action items that are performed on children components data and those actions are dependent on child component types.
Actions have 2 things: icon to represent action type and handler function. Handler function is in child component.
How to expose all the actions for particular chils component type to the parent?
The only way I can think of is to have all child components implement interface with:

property representing actions that could perform (icon and event key)
input variable where clicked action should be delivered

Is there some more elegant way to accomplish this?

Not sure i got it correctly. But i see two things i would try: component annotation, service self register (service not provided in root, but in the parents component) on loading the component, register the actions in the service ... and unregister on unload.

Have you thought about using why context api for this?

@ThomasRenger I like the idea of service registered on child component load. Could you please expand a bit more on component annotation idea?

@DerekRoberts I havent. I am not sure what you mean by context api? is that something like react context?

@DerekRoberts i am familiar with this in react but I must admin I am not in angular. Could you please point me to some docs about it?

@tlzg here you go docs If it is something you want I can draft a concept for you.

@DerekRoberts thanks for the reference but this is react. I understand the idea but I want to stick to angular solutions. If I would want some implementation like this then shared service / stora would be proper way to go.

U can store child component ref or move logic to service. Anyway some code snippets would very helpful here to clarify what u want

A parent can know all about the children using a template reference variable
<button (click)="child.doSomething('accion')"> //<--doSomething is defined in child
</button>
<child #child></child>

You can also use viewChild and as you say all the child "extends" form an interface, you can use
@ViewChild('child',{read:CommonInterface}) component!:CommonInterface

click(){
 this.component.doSomething('accion')
}

You can also use a Subject in parent and subscribe in all your child components

yeah, thats the approach. Subject is also an option. Actually, I have signal store so I can provide it in parent component and use that. Thanks!
